# Is $k$ that satisfies $\alpha^{\frac{1}{k}}<1+ε$ polynomial in $\frac1ε$?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I am doing an exercise in approximation algorithms course, and my
algorithm takes as input a constant number $\alpha$ and finds the
minimal $k_{0}$ s.t $\sqrt[k]{\alpha}<1+ε$ (this would promise
me a $1+ε$ approximation).

Clearly, such $k_{0}$ exist and I am not bothered with calculating
it within my algorithm. What I am bothered about is how my solution
behaves as $ε\to0$.

My question is this: Is $k_{0}$, which is the minimal solution for
$\sqrt[k]{\alpha}<1+ε$, polynomial in $\dfrac{1}{ε}$?

Comment: Take the logarithmon both sides and you have the answer: it is proportional.

Comment: @Helmut - I don't understand, can you please add more details ?

Comment: Muts $k_0$ be an integer ?

Comment: @Belgi Alex Francisco has read my mind. That is what I meant. The bounty came while I slept...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since$$
α^{\frac{1}{k}} < 1 + ε \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{k} \ln α < \ln(1 + ε) \Longleftrightarrow k > \frac{\ln α}{\ln(1 + ε)},
$$
then$$
k_0 = \frac{\ln α}{\ln(1 + ε)} \sim \frac{\ln α}{ε} = \ln α · \frac{1}{ε}. \quad (ε \to 0^+)
$$

Comment: +1. I presume though that one has $k_0 = \lceil \frac{\ln α}{\ln(1 + ε)} \rceil $ not $k_0 = \frac{\ln α}{\ln(1 + ε)}$ (if $k_0$ is an integer)

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Well, $[x]\sim x$ as $x\to\infty$ :)

Comment: Thank Alex. Are you sure about the approximation ? $\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$
etc', so I'm not sure we can cancel the high order powers of $\epsilon$

Comment: @Belgi $\frac{\ln(1+ε)}ε \to 1$ as $ε\to0$ is a well-known result, which can be proved by l'Hospital.

Answer (score 2):

A cruder but simpler estimate:

$\sqrt[k]{\alpha}<1+\epsilon$
is the same as
$\alpha < (1+\epsilon)^k$.

Since,
by good old Bernoulli,
$(1+\epsilon)^k
\gt 1+k\epsilon$,
if
$\alpha < 1+k\epsilon$
then $k$ is acceptable.

Therefore
$k > \dfrac{\alpha-1}{\epsilon}$
will work.

Of course,
this is not as good
as the bound
$\dfrac{\ln(\alpha)}{\epsilon}$.

Answer (score -1):

Taking logarithms on both sides of your equations we have
$$\ln(\alpha)\frac{1}{k}<\ln(1+\epsilon)$$
$$k>\frac{\ln(\alpha)}{\ln(1+\epsilon)}$$
As $\epsilon\to 0$, we can expand $\ln(1+\epsilon)$ using it's taylor expansion as $\ln(1+\epsilon)=\epsilon-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}+\frac{\epsilon^3}{3}-...\approx \epsilon-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}$ upto second order in $\epsilon$. Thus,
$$k>\frac{\ln(\alpha)}{\epsilon-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}}=\frac{\ln(\alpha)}{\epsilon(1-\frac{\epsilon}{2})}$$
Now, for small epsilon, we also have $(1-\epsilon/2)^{-1} \approx 1+\epsilon/2$. Thus,
$$k>\frac{\ln(\alpha)}{\epsilon}(1+\frac{\epsilon}{2})$$